# strange canvas rotate in Opera

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, opera

I wrote dead simple drawing with canvas:

```
var angle = 20
var k = Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * angle)
var scaleY = 0.5
var radius = 55
var pushBy = {x: 60, y: 60}

var drawArc = function (context) {
  context.setTransform(1, -k, 0, scaleY, pushBy.x, pushBy.y)
  context.beginPath()
  context.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
  context.stroke()
}

var canvas = $('canvas')
var context = canvas.getContext('2d')

drawArc(context)
```

Actually, it does exactly what I need: it draws an flattened oval rotated by 20 degrees, but... not in Opera. I also tried explicit `rotate`, it doesn't work either. In Chrome and FF everything's ok.
Am I doing something wrong? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: What do you see in Opera? Nothing at all? Your example is completely lacking in semi-colons. Is this true of your actual test file?

Comment: Opera just stretches the circle to an ellipse without skewing it. The missing semicolons definitely aren't the problem - although it's not good practice either... ;)

Comment: @Steve, I never add semicolons in Javascript because they are not required. Here's [an article on this](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/).

Comment: That's a really poor argument and I really don't recommend it, neither does the industry. [Counter article](http://benalman.com/news/2012/04/semicolons-required-in-javascript/)

Comment: Well, I don't recognize that as an argument.
I write code and it is valid, and every parser that follows the parsing rules can handle it.
This style does not introduce any kind of ambiguity. It just makes the code cleaner from what is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first approach was to draw four arcs using `arcTo()`, which I mistakenly assumed to be the universal workaround =)
Here is the code

```
var drawArcWith4ArcTo = function (context) {
  context.setTransform(1, -k, 0, scaleY, pushBy.x, pushBy.y)
  context.beginPath()
  context.moveTo(-radius, 0)
  context.lineTo(-radius, 0)
  context.arcTo(-radius, radius, 0, radius, radius)
  context.arcTo(radius, radius, radius, 0, radius)
  context.arcTo(radius, -radius, 0, -radius, radius)
  context.arcTo(-radius, -radius, -radius, 0, radius)
  context.stroke()
}
```

but it won't work in Opera for 2 reasons:

- Opera's `arcTo()` requires slightly different points as arguments =)
- It still does not apply transformation matrix to resulting path.

So I was forced to use a workaround drawing a circle using 4 Bezier Curves:

```
var drawArcWith4BezierCurves = function () {
  var kappa = 4 * (Math.sqrt(2) - 1) / 3

  return function (context) {
    context.setTransform(1, -k, 0, scaleY, pushBy.x, pushBy.y)
    context.beginPath()
    context.moveTo(-radius, 0)
    context.bezierCurveTo(
      -radius, radius * kappa,
      -radius * kappa, radius,
      0, radius
    )
    context.bezierCurveTo(
      radius * kappa, radius,
      radius, radius * kappa,
      radius, 0
    )
    context.bezierCurveTo(
      radius, -radius * kappa,
      radius * kappa, -radius,
      0, -radius
    )
    context.bezierCurveTo(
      -radius * kappa, -radius,
      -radius, -radius * kappa,
      -radius, 0
    )
    context.stroke()
  }
}

if (Prototype.Browser.Opera)
  drawArc = drawArcWith4BezierCurves()
```

Two notes:

- the resulting path is an approximation, not an absolute circle (doubt if you will ever notice this =)
- the example uses a bit of Prototype.js, but it's easy to guess what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug in Opera. If you take a look at my http://jsfiddle.net/a6anq/5/ the grid is correctly translated in both Chrome and Opera, but the oval is not. It would appear that Opera does not take into account the transform when running arc().

Comment: thank you very much, I'll now check how it works for `arcTo()`.